# Word/phrase for "staring at two things alternately"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example:

> When Liza and Josh told me their crazy plan, I did nothing; just
>   [...].

I thought about *glance*, but I think glancing is more like looking briefly, rather than staring in bewilderment.

Comment: oscillate looks between them.

Comment: ..."my gaze vacillated between them."

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are alternating, then you are not 'staring.'
2. In the context, the fact of looking at only one of the two at any point of time is of no significance.

As such, it should be fine to say "staring at **them** ."

However, if really needed, we could even say "looking alternately at them, utterly bewildered (or such)."